# Excel - I want to return the value of true if multiple non consecutive columns contain the value yes. But I also want it to ignore blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

This is what I have created so far.

=COUNTIF(E8,"<>Yes")+COUNTIF(G8,"<>Yes")+COUNTIF(I8,"<>Yes")=0

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please, check function `=COUNTIFS()`

Comment: next time please share some sample data with expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of `IF` and `OR` should be enough I think:

```
=IF(OR(E8="Yes",E8=""),IF(OR(G8="Yes",G8=""),IF(OR(I8="Yes",I8=""),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE),FALSE)
```